# What is the best way to deal with package incompatibility?

Tags: f#, nuget, version, compatibility

Installing the package `XPlot.Plotly (v. 1.4.2)` using `Nuget` failed with a message that there was incompatibility with the latest version `(v. 10.0.3)` of `Newtonsoft.Json`, which I had installed previously. The message also indicated that `version 9.0.1 of Newtonsoft.Json` would work. So I uninstalled the latest version of `Newtonsoft.Json`, installed `version 9.0.1`, and then was able to install `XPlot.Plotly`.

Is this the correct way to deal with this type of incompatibility?

Will I eventually be able to use the latest versions of both packages?

Comment: The classic DLL/Assembly/SO/SharedLibrary hell. I would register an issue on XPlot: https://github.com/fslaborg/XPlot or come up a with fix and post a PR. Since F# compiler supports encapsulating dependencies it should be possible to hide the NewtonSoft.Json dependency into XPlot.